# preg_match exact word and print out the entire line the result was found in

Tags: php, preg-match

i'm having a hard time understanding how to do this.

I want to search for a word, and then I want the search to return the word along with all the contents on the line the word was found in.

The word needs to be case sensitive so searching for TOM will not return Tom along with the results.

this is what I have tried thus far.

```
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = preg_quote($word, '/');
$numInt  = 0;
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches))
{
    $numInt = count($matches[0]);
}
```

When I run this through my function it returns the results I want, but I noticed that it isn't consistant across different keyword.

In my text file for testing I have `INT (x18)` and my function returns 18 as the count. But if I use the keyword `MORNING (x29)` the function returns 31 which is technically correct because there are 2 instances where `morning` is used.

Comment: I believe that should work if you don't escape the $, remove the backslash.

Comment: If you need the line number I think that you shouldn't read the file in one call, should be line after line...

Comment: If the keyword is on a line twice, should that be counted as one or two? (at the moment it would only be counted once).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could avoid using regex all together for this task.

Here's some code I whipped up:

```
<?php 
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

#standardise those line endings
$contents = str_replace(array("\r","\r\n","\n\r","\n"),"\n",$contents);
$lines = explode("\n", $contents);

#find your result
$result = $line_num = array();
foreach($lines as $line_num => $l)
  if(strpos($l, $word)) {
   $result[] = $l;
   $line_nums[] = $line_num;
  }

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "<br>Count:".count($result);
```

Comment: hmmm, let me try to see what this return. brb

Comment: well, it did give me the same results as my preg_match approach, but I'm still getting the case sensitive problem i had

Comment: strpos is case sensitive. stripos is case insensitive. Can you clarify which one you wanted? Also strpos only counts the first occurence. Are you saying that if it occurs twice you want that line counted twice?

Comment: The first occurance in a line, and TOM and not Tom be counted

Comment: Can you explain with the use of an example. I feel your explanation is ambiguous. So if the line was "tom spoke to TOM and found that he was busy with Tom at the tome" - and you were searching for "tom". How many results would you expect? if you are returning the entire line, do you want a count of the lines returned, or the occurences of the string?